# Highcharts Error 13 on Ajax Result and Dynamic Div

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I've tried to find a solution to why my code does not work with Highcharts. The following code results in a Error # 13, element not found.

I'm creating the element `<div id="_CPID_Chart_' + cpid +'"></div>` on the return of data from the Ajax result and append it to a td.

I know this has an easy answer, but I've been searching for an answer and nothing has come up.

```
request.done(function(data) { 
            ajaxData = data;
            $(function() {
                $('tr#_CPID_' + cpid + ' td').html(''+
'                   <div class="row">'+
'                       <div class="col-8">'+
'                           <div class="contentDiv">'+
'                               <div><p>Cross Project ID:</p>'+ ajaxData['details']['cpid'] + '</div>'+
'                               <div><p>Also Known As:</p>' + ajaxData['details']['name'] + '</div>'+
'                           </div>'+
'                       </div>'+
'                       <div class="col-8"><div id="_CPID_Chart_' + cpid + '" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px;"></div>'+
'                   </div>'+
'               ');
                Highcharts.stockChart('#_CPID_Chart_' + cpid, {
                    rangeSelector: { selected: 1 },
                    title: { text: 'CPID Chart for ' + cpid },
                    series: [{ name: cpid, data: ajaxData['magnitude'], tooltip: { valueDecimals: 8 } }]
                });
            });
        });
```

I have also tested that the div is actually there and working with the following code `$('#_CPID_Chart_' + cpid).html('Test');` instead of the Highcharts.stockChart code, and it works without any issue.

I assume I've missed something about how Highcharts renders its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving error #13 (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13) because instead of using `Highcharts.stockChart('_CPID_Chart_' + cpid, {...});` you are using `Highcharts.stockChart('#_CPID_Chart_' + cpid, {...});`. Check the corrected demo below.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ueaguauh/